# How would you go about finding the complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

```
function alg1(n)
1 a=0
2 for o=1 to n do
3     for t=1 to o do
4         for k=t to o+t do
5         a=a+1
6 return(a)
```

If anyone could guide me to how you would find the worst-case here, and how to get the output a of alg1 as a function of n, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: Subtract t from the third loop counter, it does not influence a result. Then write down number of internal loops for o=1, 2 and so on. Catch a pattern

Answer (score 3):

We can compute the exact number of increments this code executes. First, let's replace

```
for k=t to o+t do
```

with

```
for k=1 to o+1 do
```

After this change, two inner loops looks like this

```
for t=1 to o do
    for k=1 to o+1 do
```

The number of iterations of these loops is obviously `o*(o+1)`. The overall number of iterations can be calculated in the following way: 
[image]

We can exclude coefficients and lower order terms of the polynomial when using big-O notation. Therefore, the complexity is **O(n^3)**.

Comment: This comment was very helpful, thank you! Quick question, why does the innermost loop simplify to k=1 to o+1 and not k=1 to o? I thought if you were to simplify that loop by subtracting t it would come out to k=1 to o....

Comment: Is it because if you subtract t from the inner loop it would actually end up being k = 0 to o, which is the same as k=1 to o+1?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract t from the last loop so that it becomes

```
for k=0 to o do
```

Now the 2 inner most loops would run for O(o^2) time for every value of o. The answer would be

```
1^2 + 2^2 + ... n^2
```

which is equal to

> n(n+1)(2n+1)/6. Hence it would be of order of O(n^3)

Comment: Thank you! Also very helpful.